# Помогите, пожалуйста, есть клеточное поле, как подсвечивать соседей при наведении наведении мышки на элемент? Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml, mouse-event, qtquick

Сделала пока только подсветку самого элемента, а вот с соседями потерялась

```
property int pX
property int pY

MouseArea{
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        onEntered: {
            //Запоминаем позиции
            pX = brick.x
            pY = brick.y            

            brick.color = "#baa804"
        }
        onExited: brick.color = "#fcec5b"
```

Comment: Как вы строите клеточное поле? Таблица, или самогон кастомный? Надо больше кода

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, рисую один rectangle (id:brick) размером 80*80, а потом просто делаю repeat 36 штук

Comment: репит в Grid или ручное позиционирование?

Comment: соседей подсвечивать лучше через state, но сначала как бы найти этих соседей

Comment: @eri, репит в grid

Answer (score 1):

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 640
    Grid {
        columns: 8
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            id : field
            model: 64
            Rectangle {
                width: 80
                height: 80
                property var neibours : [index - 8, index + 8]
                    .concat(index % 8 == 0 ? []: [index - 1, index + 7, index - 9])
                    .concat((index - 7) % 8 == 0 ? [] : [index + 1, index - 7, index + 9])
                    .filter((neibour) => (neibour >= 0 && neibour < 64))
                border.color: 'blue'
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    onEntered: {
                        color = 'red'
                        neibours.forEach( (neibour) => field.itemAt(neibour).color = 'yellow')
                    }
                    onExited: {
                        color = 'white'
                        neibours.forEach( (neibour) => field.itemAt(neibour).color = 'white' )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно посчитать каджому элементу соседей и дергать их по индексу из Repeater-а. Соседей можно считать заранее как у меня или внутри функций.